# Firefox and iOS Safari dialog HTML element ::backdrop pseudo class animation not working

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations, pseudo-element

I am looking to use the dialog HTML element to create a modal dialog on my website. I have it working with a transition on the dialog as well as the ::backdrop pseudo element on Google Chrome (version 113.x) and Microsoft Edge (version 113.x). However, the ::backdrop pseudo class transition does not happen on Firefox or iOS Safari, it just appears. I really want to have the ::backdrop fade in on Firefox and iOS Safari.

The included code has it so that the transition is 2 seconds long.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

```js
const openButton = document.querySelector("[open-modal]");
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

openButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
{
    dialog.style.animationName = "fadeIn";
    dialog.showModal();
});

dialog.addEventListener("click", e =>
{
    dialog.classList.add("fadeOut");
    dialog.style.animationName = "fadeOut";
});

dialog.addEventListener("animationend", () =>
{
    if(dialog.style.animationName === "fadeOut")
    {
        dialog.close();
        dialog.classList.remove("fadeOut");
    }
});
```

```css
:root,
dialog.modal::backdrop
{
    --animation-duration : 2s;
}

dialog.modal
{
    animation-duration : var(--animation-duration);
    animation-name     : none;
}

@keyframes fadeIn
{
    from { transform : scale(0); }
    to   { transform : scale(1); }
}

@keyframes fadeOut
{
    from { transform : scale(1); }
    to   { transform : scale(0); }
}

dialog.modal::backdrop
{
    background         : blue;
    opacity            : 0.5;
    animation-name     : backdropFadeIn;
    animation-duration : var(--animation-duration);
}

dialog.modal.fadeOut::backdrop
{
    animation-name : backdropFadeOut;
}

@keyframes backdropFadeIn
{
    from { opacity : 0; }
}
@keyframes backdropFadeOut
{
    to   { opacity : 0; }
}
```

```html
<h1>Modal Test</h1>

<p>Click Open to open. Click anywhere else to close.</p>

<button open-modal>Open</button>

<dialog class="modal">
    <h2>Modal Dialog</h2>
</dialog>
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: could it be that animations on `::backdrop` are not yet supported in those browsers?

Comment: This is what is looking like. I can't find any documentation stating that, however.